# Laravel where method won't works correctly on my server but work right on my Mac

Tags: mysql, laravel, debian, laravel-5

I have a weird problem, this line wont fetch any record on my server but works all right on my computer, mysql and php version are same, and when i cast id field to string it's work on server (Debian), but it is risky because i use where statement with id very much. this is the code:

```
$myAnswers=Questioner::where('id',$questioner_id)->first()->getLinkedAnsweres()->where("subject_id",Auth::user()->id);
```

and when i change it to this, it's work right (cast id to string):

```
$myAnswers=Questioner::where('id',$questioner_id)->first()->getLinkedAnsweres()->where("subject_id",(string)Auth::user()->id);
```

subject_id and user id are both unsigned_integer with same size.

How can i fix this problem? Should i overwrite where method? or is there any config which cast unsigned int to string in query?

thanks

PS: Tables structure:

```
users | CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `family` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `default_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `access_level` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'subject',
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `project_limit` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `questioner_limit` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_username_unique` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |


 answers | CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `selected_option` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

Comment: Export the structure of the two tables on your local and the server. I'm willing to bet they're not the same. `SHOW CREATE TABLE <my_table_name>`. Replace `<my_table_name>` with the name of your table.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy But they are same, I edit the post and add structures to it.

Comment: same Laravel versions? I got the same kind of problems with `Response::json();` .so please verify it.

Comment: suspect that the local version is different from server, since Laravel 5.2 is continuous updating minor version these days. Type `php artisan` to see if they are the same.

Comment: @PeteHouston I just copy folder of project into the server , i install laravel with composer before and since then i just copy the folder, with artisan in it. Therefore they're same.

Comment: @Sachith see my comment above.

Comment: @DEopen the **copy** action doesn't guarantee the same version because composer will upgrade or downgrade version based on `stable` config on `https://packagist.org/`. So you really MUST to look up the version show after typing command `php artisan`, then share that **exact** version number. Otherwise, I'm not sure I can help any further.